# jQuery Validation plugin email confirmation issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Anyone has an idea why is not work the email confirmation?
I tried the custom function too. Neither built-in `equalTo` nor my custom built `confirmEmail` function don't works at all, but everything else works as expected. Even the two email validated but equality is not checked, and the custom built function also never called if I change to:

```js
confirmEmail: {
    required: true,
    confirmEmail: true
},
```

html:

```html
<input type="text" class="width_100"  id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" required="true" />
<input type="email" class="width_100" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required="true" />


<script src="vendor/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>  // Query Validation Plugin v1.19.3
```

js:

```js
$().ready(() => {
    
    const rules = {
        firstName: "required",
        lastName: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        confirmEmail: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#email"
        },
        postCode: "required",
        tnc: "required"
    };
    
    const messages = {
        firstName: "Please enter your first name.",
        lastName: "Please enter your last name.",
        confirmEmail: {
            required: "Please provide your email.",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same email as above."
        },
        postCode: "Please enter your postcode.",
        tnc: "Please accept our policy."
    };
    
    $.validator.addMethod("confirmEmail", function(value, elem) {
        return $("#email").val() == $("#confirmEmail").val();
    }, "Please enter the same email as above.");

    $("#registrationForm").validate(rules, messages);
});
```

Comment: Why would you write a custom method that you can just do with the `equalTo` rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake:
`$("#registrationForm").validate(rules, messages);`
I passed two parameters to the `.validate()` function but need only one object.

The correct syntax is:
`$("#registrationForm").validate({rules, messages});`

Answer (score -1):

You are verifying the confirmEmail field rule inside, did you try to get the value of the field by

$('#email').val() or $('#email').text()

It will give you the text value that you can compare with the email field.

You can get the value or text of an element by ID and compare it with another element with equalTo rule.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).